# How to fix this?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

I am a neophyte to Blender, currently working on a pair of woman boots starting from a Cube.

During modelling process, I need to create an opening on the mesh front and therefore I deleted an edge obtaining an oval opening, as you can see in the enclosed images: the problem is, while adjusting the opening I got some annoying pleats that makes the opening irregular and become more evident when I use *Solidify* modifier.

How can I solve this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**Thank you *@moonboots* for your answer**!

I am sure I did something wrong, since these are my first projects.

I followed your advice and I used *Bevel* modifier, which improved a little the mesh although the issue comes when I increase the thickness of the edge by using *Solidify* modifier, getting the result you can see in the enclosed image (1) and I have also tried to move a little backwards the edges of the opening as in the image (2) - although it is still far from linear, in comparison to the example you did above...

**I do appreciate your patience**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello, why don't you put the Solidify above the Bevel? The order of the modifier is taken into account

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a bit more topology to give the shape you want to your boot, but you can try this solution: Select the hole edge loop and give it bevel weight, give your object a *Solidify*, a *Bevel* (*Limit Method > Weight*) and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, here is the result:

[image]